# VS.NET 2019 where to set .net core version?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

.NET Core newbie here. I just downloaded VS.NET 2019 and created a new project. I tried to install the latest EF Core via NuGet and it tells me that my .Net Core is at 2.1.1 which is too old. So I downloaded core 2.2.0 and it still tells me I have the old version. So I create the global.json file and tell it I'm using 2.2.0 and still it doesn't work.

Googling doesn't help b/c it just says to add the global.json file. In previous verions I could click Project > Options and pick the framework but this is now gone in VS 2019.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you download the SDK or the runtime?

Comment: I downloaded the SDK. Now I see the menu option Project > app Properties where I can set the version number. Don't know why I couldn't find it before. But it's good now!

Comment: Which verison of EF Core do you try to install? EF Core releases are kinda tied to .NET Core right now, means for .NET Core 3.0 applications you need EF Core 3.0 (both preview yet, so if you dont see it in nuget, enable "include prerelease")

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change it using the menu options Project > app Properties. Don't know why it wasn't there earlier.